# Ionic-view cannot load my app: view error, status 404

Tags: ionic-framework

I have uploaded my app to Ionic successfully, because in the terminal, it says like these:

```
HanslendeMacBook-Pro:prt Hanslen$ ionic upload --note "First upload"
Uploading app....
Saved app_id, writing to ionic.io.bundle.min.js...
Successfully uploaded (812e9b74)

Share your beautiful app with someone:

$ ionic share EMAIL

Saved api_key, writing to ionic.io.bundle.min.js...
```

But when I try to open it in the Ionic View App, it shows an error, view error, status 404.